# iPhone Facebook connect : "Cookies required"

Tags: iphone, cookies, facebook

I am using FacebookConnect on the iPhone to integrate my app with Facebook.
Unfortunatly I've always "cookies required" when trying to login.

Are you also encountering this issue or do you know what may cause this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have cookies enabled in Settings → Safari → Accept Cookies?

Comment: Thanks, you've spotted the issue. Do you know if there is a way to programatically set this option or at least detect it is not set?

Thanks

Comment: I’m fairly certain that it’s not possible to change the settings programmatically. As for detection, maybe you could create a simple `UIWebView` somewhere off the screen and perform a cookie detection there. (Google for “cookie detection.”)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the settings for enabling / disabling cookies programmatically in iOS. NSHTTPCookieStorage is the class used for this. Here is how you enable it:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]
 setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

Be informed that this is a shared cookie storage that is universal to the app you are using it in. Cookies are not shared among the apps in iOS due to sandbox architecture.

The default value of this policcy is NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways, so if you are experiencing this issue while loging in through facebook connect, there are high chances that you have set its value explicitly to NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever (or altered it to some other) somewhere else in the app, and this is the side effect of that.