# iPhone: know programmatically is cookies are allowed or not

Tags: iphone, cookies, safari

I need for my app to have cookies enabled in Safari and I was wondering 2 things:
- How to detect if cookies are allowed or not
- How to allow cookies

For the moment my googling was not really successful...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: let me see if I understand correctly: you're building an web app or an app that uses UIWebView?

Comment: This should make things clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482997.

Comment: It is a regular app (not web app)

Answer (score 2):

You can't force Safari to accept cookies.

But you cat detect if they're allowed, by redirecting.

Here's how you can do:

1. At the first page you can set a verification cookie.
2. Forward to the second page.
3. At the second page, check if the verification cookie is there. If it is missing, then it doesn't accept cookies.